# Ways to stop CSS grid items from increasing simultaneously in size with other items as they grow?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a number of accordions stacked on top of one another and decided to make a simple 2 column grid layout out of them as shown below:

[image: Image of layout]

The problem is that when I expand the accordion to view the content inside it, the accordion next to it increases in height also. See image below so that you know what I mean. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? TIA :)

[image: Image of issue]

Below is my code. (I have only included one of the accordions here. There are 9 in total)

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div>
        <h3>Empowered</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="true"/>

        <div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-content">
            <h4>Red</h4>
            <p>Red is a warm colour that is often said to make you feel empowered and invigorated. It is quite a bold colour that can become overpowering if used in excess. Red is therefore best used as an accent colour.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion{
    padding: 1.3em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.accordion:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* Span used to create + symbol */
.accordion span{
    display: block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: .2em;
    background-color: var(--navy);
}

/* Rotating one of the spans vertically */
.accordion span:nth-of-type(1){
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate( 2px, 2px);
    position: relative;
    left: .08em;
    top: .08em;
}
/* Invisible checkbox that acts as click receiver */
.accordion input{
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: -1.8em;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
/* Moving the spans to the right of the accordion div */
.accordion div div:nth-of-type(1){
    float: right;
    margin-right: -1.9em;
    margin-top: -1.1em;
    z-index: 1;
}

.accordion h4{
    clear: right;
}

.accordion-content{
    display: none;
}

.accordion input:checked ~ .accordion-content{ 
display: initial;
}
```

At 750px screen width I have made a 2 column layout:

```
.colour-and-mood .container div:nth-of-type(1){
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
}

/* Keeping the span display as block. */
.colour-and-mood .container div:nth-of-type(1) div:nth-of-type(1){
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the grid element (the element styled with `display: grid;`) add the style `align-items: start;`. The default value is `stretch`, which is what you’re seeing in action.

(PS. If you had included a working snippet in your question (a snippet is Stack Overflow's equivalent of a Codepen or a jsFiddle), one which demonstrated the problem, then I would have been able to include an edited snippet in my answer, one which demonstrated the solution.)